# Does object in java created on heap before Constructor is invoked?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, heap-memory

When overridden methods are called from the Constructor of the base class then also as per the run time polymorphism concept the method defined in the sub class gets invoked. I wonder as how this is taken care of in the JVM, when control is in the base class constructor the constructor of the sub class is yet to be called and hence Object is not yet completely constructed.

I understand the ill effects of calling overriden methods from base class constructor but just wish to understand as how this is made possible.

I feel object in the heap is created before constructor is invoked and as constructor is invoked the properties are initialized.  Please provide your valuable inputs for the above.

Below is the code demonstrating the same.

**Base.java**

```
public class Base {
    public Base() {
            System.out.println("Base constructor is executing...");
            someMethod();
    }

    public void someMethod() {
            System.out.println("someMethod defined in Base class executing...");
    }
}
```

**Sub.java**

```
public class Sub extends Base{
    public Sub() {
            System.out.println("Sub constructor is executing...");
    }
    @Override
    public void someMethod() {
            System.out.println("someMethod defined in Sub class executing...");
    }
}
```

**Client.java**

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Sub obj = new Sub();
    }
}
```

**Output on console is**

Base constructor is executing...

someMethod defined in Sub class executing...

Sub constructor is executing...

Comment: The short answer is yes. New object instances are created with the `dup` opcode, constructors are only called after that. You can create your own objects without invoking a constructor too, using deserialization for example.

Comment: @nits.kk, have a look at this article: https://www.artima.com/designtechniques/initializationP.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does object in java created before Constructor is invoked ?

Yes, otherwise you would not have an object to initialise.

At the byte code level, the object is created first, and then the constructor is called, passing in the object to initialise. The internal name for a constructor is `<init>` and it's return type is always `void` meaning it doesn't return the object, only initialise it.

Note: `Unsafe.allocateInstance` will create an object without calling a constructor and is useful for de-serialization.

Comment: The relevant [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4) reference: `The new object contains new instances of all the fields declared in the specified class type and all its superclasses. As each new field instance is created, it is initialized to its default value (§4.12.5).`

Comment: @biziclop AFAIK, the object is created all at once, rather than one field at a time +1

Comment: @Peter Lawrey , biziclop: thanks for he answers, nicely explained...does this has got something to do with as why class fields are initialized to default values them selves but the local variables always needs to be explicitly  initialized before use.

Comment: @nits.kk the difference is based on what the compiler can easily check.  The compiler does ensure that `final` fields are always initialised.

Comment: @PeterLawrey why local variables always needs to be **explicitly** initialized before use but it is not mandatory for the class fields. Class fields get auto initialized [primitives with default values, object references with null], same could have been done for local variables but its not been done, we need to do explicit initialization for local variables,

Comment: @nits.kk it is done for `final` fields, however checking non-final fields mean checking how the class is used which is far more complicated, possibly unsolvable. e.g. you would have to check that the setter of a field is called before the getter in all possible code paths.

Comment: @nits.kk Local variables only "exist" from the first time they're assigned a value until the end of the block they were declared in. And every time someone invokes the method, they see their own values for the local variables. While fields exist from the moment the object is created until it is collected, and everyone sees the same field. (Though not always the same value in a multithreaded context, but that's a whole different can of worms.) But in theory local variables could be automatically initialised to `null`, `0` or `false` too, it was just decided that they won't be.

Comment: @biziclop if the compiler/IDE could detect unsafe thread access for you and auto-fix it, I think we would be out of a job. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Haha, quite possibly. :) No, I meant the other way around, they could've decided not to check that local variables are always written before they're read and just initialised them to a default value at the point of declaration. It would be worse though.

Comment: @biziclop: I feel using variables with default value is of no use [until the programmer decides himself to do so by explicitly initializing with defaluts like null, o, false], So Compiler forces the programmer for explicit initialization. Also local variables are used only within scope of method body si programmer is forced to initialize in method. For the instance variables I feel Comment by Peter is useful, Compiler can not check as there may be so many different ways a instance may be initialized [constructor, lazy initialization, setter getter]. It only checks for final instance variables.

Comment: @nits.kk Note: final fields have to be initialised in all constructors which is reasonable to check for.